# `Xamarin.Android` SensorManager.RegisterListener() returns `false`

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

It is strange that the sensors
`SensorType.StepDetector`, and `SensorType.StepCounter`
do not work for me.

They return `false` already on `SensorManager.RegisterListener()`
such that I cannot do anything afterwards.
This is not the case for `SensorType.Accelerometer`, which returns `true`.
Also, I am checking the availability of the step sensors by a method `ShouldFeaturesAvailable()` as in the code. This returns `true`.
I present the minimal code for you to consider
why this is the case. Any advice, please?

I also added in `AndroidManifest.xml` that

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector" />
```

The example code in `MainActivity.cs` reads

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;

using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Hardware;  /* ISensorEventListener    */

namespace test
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, ISensorEventListener
    {
        public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {  }
        public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, SensorStatus accuracy) {  }
        bool ShouldFeaturesAvailable(PackageManager pm)
        {
            // Require at least Android KitKat
            int currentApiVersion = (int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt;
            // Check that the device supports the step counter and detector sensors
            return currentApiVersion >= 19
                && pm.HasSystemFeature(Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureSensorStepCounter)
                && pm.HasSystemFeature(Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureSensorStepDetector);
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            var shouldWork = ShouldFeaturesAvailable(PackageManager);  //true

            var sensorManager = (SensorManager)GetSystemService(SensorService);

            var isAccelerometerRegistered = sensorManager.RegisterListener(this,
                sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Accelerometer),
                SensorDelay.Ui);  //true

            var isStepDetectorRegistered = sensorManager.RegisterListener(this,
                sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.StepDetector),
                SensorDelay.Ui);  //false

            var isStepCounterRegistered = sensorManager.RegisterListener(this,
                sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.StepCounter),
                SensorDelay.Ui);  //false
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />`